# NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getMapAsync

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I'm trying to revitalize an old Google Maps app that I made back in 2014. Had no problems apart from one: Trying to initialize a map inside a custom made method that I'm calling above in the same class, I get this error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getMapAsync(Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/OnMapReadyCallback;)V in class Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment' appears in /data/data/com.packagename.appname/files/instant-run/dex/slice-google-play-services_013f7ca48f60d837bd691f2b8fafce962adefa56-classes.dex)
```

Here's the method itself:

```
private void initilizeMap()
{
    if (mGoogleMap == null) {
        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You have to accept to enjoy all app's services!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Method initializeMap() is called above its declaration, and the Android Monitor is pointing to that line as well as the line:

```
MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
```

The fragment is correctly declared inside the layout. Also, below, I've overriden the method onMapReady:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
{
    mGoogleMap = googleMap;
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

I have no idea what's causing this problem.

EDIT (build.gradle dependencies):

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile files('libs/android-google-maps-api13.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
}
```

Comment: Could you share your `build.gradle`?

Comment: I assume you want to see the dependencies? Added them above.

Answer (score 1):

The `MapFragment` instance that you see at runtime does not have the expected method. It looks like you compiled with a newer version then you use to run your application.

Comment: Do I need a SupportFragmentMap instead? Or some other type?